# Servicenow contains search

Tags: search, contains, servicenow, startswith

The servicenow catalog item in which the search item should be implemented with " conatins" logic

I tried using user prefernce setting , but it will have a impact on all ctalogs , but i need a conatins logic only in one catalog

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.